# Reserving and Committing memory if needed

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, virtualalloc

What are the downsides of using VirtualAlloc for arrays, reserving large chunk of address space, and committing pages when they are needed?
For example if I know max cap for my array, I can reserve address space for it, using VirtualAlloc, and commit memory if I actually need it.

Unlike std::vector in this case, all pointers will remain valid after adding need pages to array.

I understand that this is not suitable for all arrays in program, but in the case when I need to save a pointers after array grows/resize?

Or should I just use std::deque?  But with std::deque I gonna lose continues address space.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour unless the array contains [Implicit Lifetime Types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType), or you use placement new in the newly committed space. See also [Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

Comment: I can managed that ;)

Comment: Why don't you try defining an allocator for `vector`. The hint version of `allocate` method may come in handy, if the specific implementation of vector actually uses it. I don't know if std demands that containers should use it when they can, but I guess implementors do not miss the optimization options this offers.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualAlloc is a low-level Windows API that provides lots of options for memory allocation. It can be useful in specific situations, such as when you need to share memory directly with another process. [However, it is not recommended for general-purpose memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872072/whats-the-differences-between-virtualalloc-and-heapalloc).

One downside of using VirtualAlloc for arrays is that it can only allocate memory in larger chunks. [This means that if your address space becomes fragmented, you have no recourse but to release and rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513363/for-what-do-i-need-to-use-virtualalloc-virtualallocex). Additionally, VirtualAlloc manages pages in the Windows virtual memory system, while HeapAlloc allocates from a specific OS heap. You are unlikely to ever need to use either of them.

In contrast, std::vector automatically manages memory allocation and reallocation for you. It can grow dynamically as needed and all pointers remain valid after adding new pages to the array.

[If you need to save pointers to elements in a container after it grows or resizes, `std::deque` could be a good option](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-vs-vector-in-c-stl/). Unlike `std::vector`, which stores its elements in a contiguous block of memory and may need to reallocate and move its elements when it grows, `std::deque` stores its elements in multiple blocks of memory. This means that when a `std::deque` grows, it can add new blocks of memory without invalidating pointers to its existing elements.

However, keep in mind that std::deque has some trade-offs compared to std::vector. For example, [it may not have as fast random access to its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436020/whats-the-difference-between-deque-and-list-stl-containers) and may use more memory due to the overhead of managing multiple blocks of memory.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, VirtualAlloc solves downsides of deque, and keeps upsides of vector. 
Yes it's page granularity, but it is not problem for large arrays. And small arrays I can preallocate if needed anyway

Comment: I see your point @Heorhiy `VirtualAlloc` does provide benefits of both vector and deque. If you are preallocating then I would say `VirtualAlloc` is best for your case.

Comment: `VirtualAlloc` is a Windows specific API, so if you need your code to be portable to other platforms, you may have to use a different memory allocation function like `vector` or `deque`.